# Attach two 3d numpy arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was wondering how I can attach two 3d numpy arrays in python?

For example, I have one with shape `(81,81,61)` and I would like to get instead a `(81,81,122)` shape array by attaching the original array to itself in the z direction.

Comment: this question was first so I don't want to flag it as a duplicate, but there's another identical question with more votes and a slightly better answer (also from Alex Riley): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357617/append-2d-array-to-3d-array-extending-third-dimension

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to use [`np.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) which concatenates the arrays along the third axis (*d* is for *depth*).

For example:

```
>>> a = np.arange(8).reshape(2,2,2)
>>> np.dstack((a, a))
array([[[0, 1, 0, 1],
        [2, 3, 2, 3]],

       [[4, 5, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 6, 7]]])

>>> np.dstack((a, a)).shape
(2, 2, 4)
```

You could also use `np.concatenate((a, a), axis=2)`.