# Append 2D array to 3D array, extending third dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I have an array `A` that has shape `(480, 640, 3)`, and an array `B` with shape `(480, 640)`.

How can I append these two as one array with shape `(480, 640, 4)`?

I tried `np.append(A,B)` but it doesn't keep the dimension, while the `axis` option causes the `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use [`dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
>>> np.dstack((A, B)).shape
(480, 640, 4)
```

This handles the cases where the arrays have different numbers of dimensions and stacks the arrays along the third axis.

Otherwise, to use `append` or `concatenate`, you'll have to make `B` three dimensional yourself and specify the axis you want to join them on:

```
>>> np.append(A, np.atleast_3d(B), axis=2).shape
(480, 640, 4)
```

Comment: Or to use the most basic methods: `np.concatenate(A, B[...,None], axis=2)`

Comment: @hpaulj Getting error `TypeError: concatenate() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
`

Comment: @piepi, did you look at the `concatenate` docs?  They have priority over my old comments.  In any case, I should have written `np.concatenate([A, B[...,None]], axis=2)`.  That is, put the arrays in a list

Comment: @piepi, did you look at the `concatenate` docs?  They have priority over my old comments.  In any case, I should have written `np.concatenate([A, B[...,None]], axis=2)`.  That is, put the arrays in a list

Comment: Coming from Matlab, holy **** why do I have to be googling for 15 minutes to find this. It should be obvious that concatenate( <M x N x Q>, <M x N x 1>) should result in <M x  N x Q + 1>.

Answer (score 3):

using `np.stack` should work
but the catch is both arrays should be of 2D form.

`np.stack([A,B])`