# How can I append a multidimensional array to a new dimension with Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an empty list: `x = []`.

I have a numpy array, `y`, of shape: `(180, 161)`. I can't necessarily define `x` to be an `np.empty` of a particular shape, because I won't know the shape of `y` ahead of time.

I want to append `y` to `x` so that `x` will have a `.shape` of `(1, 180, 161)`.

Then if I append more, I want it to be `(n, 180, 161)`

I tried `.append` and `.stack`, but I've had a variety of errors:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 3 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)
```

And so on. It seems that this should be simple, but it's strangely difficult.

Comment: Numpy arrays and lists aren't interchangeable, so you could have a list of numpy arrays of shape (180, 161), but the list of numpy arrays won't have a .shape attribute like numpy arrays do.  Do you want a 3d numpy array? If so starting with a list x may not be the best approach.

Comment: I want `x` to then be a numpy array when I append

Comment: This is what you're asking for in the second step I believe. I'm not sure why starting with an empty list is useful though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357617/append-2d-array-to-3d-array-extending-third-dimension

Comment: You need need to take array shapes seriously.  `[]` is a list, `np.arrray([])` is a (0,) shape array.  You can't join that with a (180,161) shape.  The shapes have nothing in common!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all items in `x` have the same shape, you can first construct a `list` and then construct the NumPy array from the list.

There, you have two options:

- `np.array()` which is faster but not flexible
- [`np.stack()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy-stack) which is slower but allows you to choose over which axis should the stack happen (it is roughly equivalent to `np.array().transpose(...).copy()`

The code would look like:

```
import numpy as np


n = 100
x = [np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 20)) for _ in range(n)]

# same as: y = np.stack(x, 0)
y = np.array(x)

print(y.shape)
# (100, 10, 20)
```

---

Of course this line:

```
x = [np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 20)) for _ in range(n)]
```

can be replaced with:

```
x = []
for _ in range(n):
    x.append(np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 20)))
```

---

You could also use `np.append()`, e.g.:

```
def stacker(arrs):
    result = arrs[0][None, ...]
    for arr in arrs[1:]:
        result = np.append(result, arr[None, ...], 0)
    return result
```

but with horrific performances:

```
n = 1000
shape = (100, 100)
x = [np.random.randint(0, n, shape) for _ in range(n)]

%timeit np.array(x)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 21.1 ms per loop
%timeit np.stack(x)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 21.6 ms per loop
%timeit stacker(x)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 11 s per loop
```

and, as you can see, performance-wise, the `list`-based method is way faster.

Comment: All `y` will have the same shape. But how will the stacking work?

Comment: What do you mean? I have linked the documentation. Is there something not clear in there?

Answer (score 2):

You can reshape `y` to be `(1, *y.shape)`.

Then for appending an array you can say: 
`y_1 = np.vstack((y, new_arr))`

where `y_1.shape` produces a `(2, *y.shape)` numpy array. 
To save memory you can say `y = np.vstack((y, new_arr))`

You might have to reshape your array to `(1, *y.shape)` however.

This is a very basic example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((1,2,3))
b = np.ones((1,2,3))
np.vstack((a,b)).shape # (2,2,3)
```

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you keep `x` as a `list` then if you just want to maintain the shape by appending, it is possible:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> x = []

>>> y = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

>>> x.append(y)

>>> np.shape(x)
(1, 3, 4)

>>> x.append(y)

>>> np.shape(x)
(2, 3, 4)

>>> for i in range(10):
...     x.append(y)


>>> np.shape(x)
(12, 3, 4)
```

But considering you are dealing with `np.array`s it may not be convenient for you to keep `x` as `list`, so you may try this:

```
>>> x = np.array(x)

>>> x.shape
(12, 3, 4)


>>> y[None,...].shape
(1, 3, 4)

>>> np.append(x, y[None,...],axis=0).shape
(13, 3, 4)
```

**Word of caution:**
As pointed out by [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60855200/how-can-i-append-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-new-dimension-with-numpy/60855386#comment107669451_60855386) :

`np.append` should be avoided, as it is extremely slow, probably only faster than:

```
x = np.array([*x, y])
```

The correct usage would be:

```
x = np.concatenate([x, y[None,...]], axis=0)
```

Either way, concatenating or appending is generally a speed bump in `numpy`. So unless you absolutely need to create an array this way, you should work with lists. Also most functions applied to `np.arrays` work on `list`s as well. Note, functions applied to arrays, not methods of an `np.array` object. For example:

```
>>> x = list((1, 2, 3, 4))
>>> np.shape(x)
(4,)
>>> x.shape
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-100-9f2b259887ef>", line 1, in <module>
    x.shape

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

So I would suggest appending to list, and then after you have done appending all the arrays, convert the list to `np.array` if you require.

Comment: Don't use `np.append`!  `np.concatenate([x, y[None,...]], axis=0)` is the correct usage.  And don't even do that repeatedly.  List append is much easier to use and faster.

Comment: Correct, should have added. Wanted to follow OP's terminology. Will edit, thanks.