# Numpy: How to append 2d array to the end of 3d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I create a masked array `A` with shape `(8,1,51,120)` and a data masked array `B` with shape `(11232,51,120)`.

Now I make a loop to select `bar` of `B[step,:,:]` array and append it at the end of `A[foo,0,:,:]`. Here is some pseudo-code to describe what I want:

```
for step in range(B.shape[0]):
    foo = select_func(step)
    A[foo,A.shape[1]-1,:,:].append(B[step,:,:])

print(A[foo,:,:,:].shape)
```

Finally I want `A[foo,:,:,:].shape = (bar,51,120)`.

It turns out very hard to append `B` to `A` using `np.ma.dstack(` or `np.ma.append(` not only because `A` not change as I do but also it made new masked array.

I try this: [Append 2D array to 3D array, extending third dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357617/append-2d-array-to-3d-array-extending-third-dimension), but I want my original `A` array grow up not to make new array.

Comment: have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357617/append-2d-array-to-3d-array-extending-third-dimension?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I checked it. It can't broadcast results to the original array the way I want

Comment: In `numpy` you can't 'grow up' an array.  You can only make a new array with values copied from the originals.  Arrays are not the same lists in this regard.  And the 'joining' functions (`np.concatenate` and the 'stack' relatives) all require some degree of shape compatibility.