# Append 2d array to 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray

I have an array of shape `(3, 250, 15)`.

I want to append to it a 2d array of shape `(250,15)` so that I have a final shape of `(4,250,15)`.
I tried with `dstack` and `np.stack` but it does not work.

Can someone give me a suggestion ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append 2D array to 3D array, extending third dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357617/append-2d-array-to-3d-array-extending-third-dimension)

Comment: @blunova The accepted answer on that Q (use `dstack`) doesn't work in this case, where the 'missing' axis is the first one. Personally I think adding an axis and using some form of stack is a more general solution.

Comment: @kwinkunks I'm sorry, you are right! Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a dimension (in other words, an axis) to the 2-D array, for example:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((3, 250, 15))
b = np.ones((250, 15))

c = np.vstack([a, b[None, :, :]])
```

Now `c` has shape `(4, 250, 15)`.

If you're not into the `None` axis trick, you could achieve something similar with [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html?highlight=newaxis#numpy.newaxis) or [`np.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can't append a 2D array to a 3D array directly, so you should first expand the axes of the smaller array to become 3D and then append normally. `np.expand_dims(b, axis=0)` will insert the missing first-axis to array `b`. Now append the two 3D arrays, `np.append(a, b, axis=0)`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((3, 250, 15))
b = np.ones((   250, 15))

b = np.expand_dims(b, axis=0)
c = np.append(a, b, axis=0)
```

which works as expected.

```
print(c.shape)
 (4, 250, 15)
```